# MasterDataService 2017 Plugin not connecting in Office 365 Excel App (SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql-server, excel, mds

We have recently migrated from SQL Server 2014 to 2017 and have upgraded to Windows 10. Post migration activity we have installed the MasterDataServices 2017 plug in for Excel. The plug in appears on my Office 365 Excel App. However when I try to add a connection and test the connection, it either hangs or nothing happens.

After searching online I saw an option to disable and re-enable the plug in for Excel, this appears to have worked for some people. However this did not work for me either.

Since Excel is the primary front end our business users use to manage this data - we are now stuck with obsolete data. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Please let me know if there is any other detail that is required from my end to add clarity to this question.

Update 1 : Link to the tactical fix of disabling and enabling the plug in
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/686e92ba-9d4d-4fe5-9ebc-c9e207a710fb/mds-2016-excel-plug-in-not-working

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sql-server-2017-mds-add-in-for-excel-does-not/11c6d519-f92a-448f-b338-ec6b430ad867

UPDATE 2 : Further i found below on Cumulative Update 13 helping with issue , but we are already on 18.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4469292/cannot-connect-to-the-mds-database-using-the-mds-add-in-for-excel

Comment: Please add the web-link where you found disabling and re-enabling works. That could be helpful

Comment: I've updated the query to now include the link .